# Search through an array with two values

Tags: php, arrays

Good day,

I'm trying to search through an array.

I have two IDs (productId, secondaryProductId) in an array (`$package`) with some other data:

```
array (size=7)
  'title' => string 'Compleet' (length=8)
  'productId' => string '102' (length=5)
  'price' => string '45.75' (length=5)
  'secondaryProductId' => string '150' (length=5)
  'secondaryPrice' => string '58.75' (length=5)
```

I have an array with arrays (`$availableProducts`):

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'product_id' => int 102
      'description' => string 'some description for 102'
      'order_link' => string 'some/link/102'
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'product_id' => int 150
      'description' => string 'some description for 150'
      'order_link' => string 'some/link/150'
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'product_id' => int 160
      'description' => string 'some description for 160'
      'order_link' => string 'some/link/160'
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'product_id' => int 140
      'description' => string 'some description for 140'
      'order_link' => string 'some/link/140'
```

What I want to achieve is to search both product IDs in the `$availableProducts` array.

If they exists (like 102 and 150 with there description and link exist) I want the description and link to be set in the first array where both the product IDs are.

Like this:

```
array (size=7)
  'title' => string 'Complete' (length=8)
  'productId' => string '102' (length=5)
  'price' => string '45.75' (length=5)
  'secondaryProductId' => string '150'
  'secondaryPrice' => string '58.75'
  'description' => string 'some description for 102'
  'order_link' => string 'link/for/102'
  'secondaryDescription' => string 'some description for 150'
  'secondaryOrder_link' => string 'some/link/150'
```

If one of them doesn't exist I want it's ID and price to either be removed or set as an empty string (doesn't matter).

Like this:

```
array (size=7)
  'title' => string 'Complete' (length=8)
  'productId' => string '102' (length=5)
  'price' => string '45.75' (length=5)
  'secondaryProductId' => string ''
  'secondaryPrice' => string ''
  'description' => string 'some description for 102'
  'order_link' => string 'link/for/102'
```

What I have tried so far with a foreach loop:

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($availableProducts as $product) {
    if ($package['productId'] == $product->product_id) {
        $package['orderLink'] = $product->order_link;
        $finalArray[] = $package;
    }

    if ($package['secondaryProductId'] == $product->product_id) {
        $package['secondaryOrderLink'] = $product->order_link;
        $finalArray[] = $package;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. At first it looks fine to set the `orderLink`, but then it kind of runs double:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'productId' => string '102' (length=5)
      'price' => string '35.75' (length=5)
      'secondaryProductId' => string '150' (length=5)
      'secondaryPrice' => string '48.75' (length=5)
      'orderLink' => string 'link/for/102'
  1 => 
    array (size=6)
      'productId' => string '102' (length=5)
      'price' => string '35.75' (length=5)
      'secondaryProductId' => string '150' (length=5)
      'secondaryPrice' => string '48.75' (length=5)
      'orderLink' => string 'link/for/102'
      'secondaryOrderLink' => string 'link/for/150'
```

I've tried playing around a bit, also tried in_array. But I clearly do something wrong. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `array_intersect_key(array_column($availableProducts, null, 'product_id'), array_filp([$array1['productId'], $array1['secondaryProductId']])))` - cheers.  If the arrays were in a usable format I would make an example (such as output with `var_export`)

Comment: your attempt in creating your desired structure is incorrect, since the one you desired has only one dimension (meaning flat), and your attempt creates a two dimensioned one: `$finalArray[] = $package;` see, you're continually pushing

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (truncated version)

```
$availableProducts = [
    0 => [
      'product_id' =>  102,
      'description' =>  'some description for 102',
      'order_link' =>  'some/link/102',
   ], 1 => [
      'product_id' =>  150,
      'description' =>  'some description for 150',
      'order_link' =>  'some/link/150'
   ], 2 => [
      'product_id' =>  160,
      'description' =>  'some description for 160',
      'order_link' =>  'some/link/160'
    ]
 ];

 $array1 = [
  'title' =>  'Compleet',
  'productId' =>  '102',
  'price' =>  '45.75',
  'secondaryProductId' =>  '150',
  'secondaryPrice' =>  '58.75',
];

print_r(
    array_intersect_key(
        array_column($availableProducts, null, 'product_id'),
        array_flip([$array1['productId'], $array1['secondaryProductId']])
   )
);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [102] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 102
            [description] => some description for 102
            [order_link] => some/link/102
        )

    [150] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 150
            [description] => some description for 150
            [order_link] => some/link/150
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8a689828a44cadee4d23c7dc1684bacbe0562e83)

- note - this only works if `product_id` is unique in `$availableProducts`

Basically `array_column($availableProducts, null, 'product_id')` will restructure your array using `product_id` as the key (no duplicate ids), then you can get the intersection between this and an array with the 2 id's you need to find. I filped it because I am to lazy to make them as keys, which they need to be for `array_intersect_key` (obviously) to work.

`array_column` - is extremely powerful for array to array comparison.  There are several neat tricks you can do with it...

The above shows you how to filter out only the 2 you want, But if you just want to update the original array (`$array1` in this example) is a simple matter of doing this:

```
$res = array_column($availableProducts, null, 'product_id');

$array1['productId'] = $res[$array1['productId']]['description'];
$array1['secondaryProductId'] = $res[$array1['secondaryProductId']]['description'];
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [title] => Compleet
    [productId] => some description for 102
    [price] => 45.75
    [secondaryProductId] => some description for 150
    [secondaryPrice] => 58.75
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5cd7a6d05ef402b57c598d2c029b42ef3b87877)

See with the product ID's as the keys (see output from example one) we can just use the value to get that segment of the multi-dimensional array by it's product_id - directly.

Obviously it's pretty easy to do this too now

```
 $res = array_column($availableProducts, null, 'product_id');

 $array1['productId'] =['description' => $res[$array1['productId']]['description'], 'order_link' => $res[$array1['productId']]['order_link']];
 $array1['secondaryProductId'] =['description' => $res[$array1['secondaryProductId']]['description'], 'order_link' => $res[$array1['secondaryProductId']]['order_link']];
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Compleet
    [productId] => Array
        (
            [description] => some description for 102
            [order_link] => some/link/102
        )

    [price] => 45.75
    [secondaryProductId] => Array
        (
            [description] => some description for 150
            [order_link] => some/link/150
        )

    [secondaryPrice] => 58.75
)
```

I'm not sure what you want as the end result, but maybe this will help you.

Enjoy